# Multiple Update Firebase Database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, qr-code

I'm creating an application with which the student will scan the QR code of a class created by a teacher.

After the student scans it, her/his details will store in the class list data. My problem is when I try to change the first name, middle name, and last name, only the first box is updating, while the 2nd and 3rd box are not.

[image: The first oblong is the user ID of the teacher and the second one is the value of the QR code for the class he/she created.]

Can someone here please help me?

**Here's the code that updates the first box:**

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("users").child("student").child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();
    String newFirstName = oldEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String newMiddleName = middlename.getText().toString().trim();
    String newLastName = lastname.getText().toString().trim();
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        ref.child("users").child("student").child(uid).child("firstname").setValue(newFirstName);
        ref.child("users").child("student").child(uid).child("middlename").setValue(newMiddleName);
        ref.child("users").child("student").child(uid).child("lastname").setValue(newLastName);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(AccountSettingsActivity.this, "Failed to update name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

**Here's the code that updates the second and third boxes:**

```
ref.child("users").child("teacher").child("class").child("Listofstudents").child(user.getUid().toString().trim()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();
    String newFirstName = oldEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String newMiddleName = middlename.getText().toString().trim();
    String newLastName = lastname.getText().toString().trim();

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            ref.child("users").child("teacher").child(ref.child("teacher").getKey()).child("class").child(ref.child("class").getKey()).child("Listofstudents").child(user.getUid().toString().trim()).child("firstname").setValue(newFirstName);
            ref.child("users").child("teacher").child(ref.child("teacher").getKey()).child("class").child(ref.child("class").getKey()).child("Listofstudents").child(user.getUid().toString().trim()).child("middlename").setValue(newMiddleName);
            ref.child("users").child("teacher").child(ref.child("teacher").getKey()).child("class").child(ref.child("class").getKey()).child("Listofstudents").child(user.getUid().toString().trim()).child("lastname").setValue(newLastName);
            // TODO: handle the case where the data already exists
        }
        else {
            // TODO: handle the case where the data does not yet exist
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(AccountSettingsActivity.this, "Failed to update name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a `listener` in order to make an update in a Firebase database.

Please see my answer at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755198/how-can-i-update-my-information-in-different-location-android-firebase/44759419).

Hope it helps.