# How can i update my information in different location? Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Click this to see Firebase Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTTbD.png)

I want to update my information (firstname, middlename, lastname) which is in a different location. I'm updating my information using student account. It only update under student but I don't know how to update it under teacher. If I update my first name, middle name, last name, I want my first name, middle name, and last name update also under the two section under the class. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a record in a Firebase database, you can use `setValue()` method directly on the `reference`. Assuming that `teacher` is the direct child of the Firebase root, you can use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference firstNameRef = rootRef.child("teacher").child(teacherId).child("class").child(classId).child("Listofstudents").child(listId).child("firstname");
firstNameRef.setValue("New Name");
```

In which `teacherId`, `classId` and `listId` are those random generated keys that i see in your database.

If you want to update the same data, in a different location, just add another reference to desired location and use the same `setValue()` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My problem is how can i get the user id of the teacher and class name made by the teacher if i'm using the student account? That's my problem. I wish you can help me regarding this problem.

Comment: You can get the teacher and class name made by the teacher, only to display, not to update them. You can get them all. But not having a specific one, you cannot go deeper into your database. Would you like me to write some code to display them? I repet, not to update them.

Comment: Yes can you write some code please. It is possible to update first name, middle name and last name under the 2 class name using student account? if i change those 3, i want all first name, middle name and last name must also update but i cant because the i don't know how to get the user id of teacher and class name. based on your code above. listid is the user id of the student which is easy to get.

Comment: The final answer to this question is: You cannot update those values under the `teacher` node if don't have the `teacherId`. With other words, It is NOT possible to update first name, middle name and last name under the 2 class name using student account. Not knowing the `teacherId`, it's impossible to iterate.

Comment: What if i use teacher's account, is this possible ? My problem now is how can i get the specific user id of the student ? example my user id is 12345 and everytime that i change those 3. those information under 2 section will base on the first name, middle name and last name.

Comment: If you use teacher account it's possible, becase you have the `teacherId`. Using the code above, you'll make it work. Having the `userId`, will also work.

Comment: I tried to update it using teacher's account but it still not updating. I found out that firebase supports multi path update but what if my database structure has a lot of my user id which is auto generated?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, Firebase supports multi path update but this doesn't mean that you can update a value in the database if don't have an id. With other words, skiping a child. That's no possible.

Comment: Yes. I used different way to fix it but still thanks for helping.